# Data type double not converting to factor

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I am trying to convert my column within the data frame from "double" to a "factor", but its not working

I am trying to convert the "double" data type to "factor" but its converting it to an integer. I have tried a couple of other things from stackoverflow but nothing seems to work. I have provided my code below along with console output.

Task 1.5 - Change class type from Integer to Factor

```
typeof(iLPdf$class)  #check type
iLPdf$class <- as.factor(iLPdf$class)
typeof(iLPdf$class)  #check type


[1] "double"
iLPdf$class <- as.factor(iLPdf$class)
typeof(iLPdf$class)  #check type
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: Don't check with `typeof`, levels are represented as integers. Check with `is.factor`. See this for instance: `typeof(iris$Species)`.

Comment: Check `class(iLPdf$class)`

Comment: Cool thanks guys! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `typeof` checks the internal representation of an object. Factors are represented as integers. To check that something is actually a factor, use `is.factor` instead. From the docs:

> typeof determines the (R internal) type or storage mode of any object

To verify this "claim", you can check the well known iris Species' column which is a factor. `typeof(iris$Species)` will however return `integer` because to R factors are integers.

Using  `is.factor` is a better option, this ultimately boils down to the [difference between  types and classes in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/mode-class-and-type-of-r-objects).

```
is.factor(iris$Species)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation mate! Thanks for that =)